# How to constrain an auto lambda parameter to a pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, auto, pointer-to-member

I have a generic lambda function that needs to accept a pointer-to-member-function as a parameter. I can of course simply use `auto` on its own and the compiler will deduce the correct type. However, where possible, I prefer to decorate my auto parameters with `*`, `&` and `const` where appropriate, thus better communicating the nature and intent of the deduced type. If I simply make the `auto` parameter an `auto*`, I get a compiler error, which I'm not really surprised by as `auto*` signifies a regular pointer, not a pointer-to-member. Is there some syntax for constraining an `auto` parameter to accept a pointer-to-member, or should I just use `auto` and forget about it?

```cpp
int main()
{
    struct S { void m() {} };

    //auto l = [](auto* pmf) // ERROR
    //auto l = [](const auto& pmf) // Works, but uh, bit misleading I think
    auto l = [](auto pmf)
    {
        S s;
        (s.*pmf)();
    };

    l(&S::m);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare it as:

```
auto l = [](auto S::*pmf)
```

It does tie the pointer to a `S` type, but it makes sense because it is that way you will use it.

Comment: Cool, that's what I was after, thanks. In my use case S is a fixed type, but I guess if it wasn't you could use `auto l = []<typename T>(auto T::* pmf)`, assuming you have C++20.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 you can constrain it with a concept:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept MemberPointer = std::is_member_pointer_v<T>;

void test() {
    auto foo = [](MemberPointer auto memPtr) {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++20 `requires`-clause to do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

auto l = [](auto pmf) requires std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(pmf)>
{
  S s;
  (s.*pmf)();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MsTYrrWhc)